# Why does Juno debugger try to search files in some random directory?

Tags: debugging, directory, path, julia, juno-ide

I'd like to use the debugger in Juno. I have multiple files, say *file1*, *file2* and *file3*, all stored in one directory, say *directory1*. However, when I try to run the debugger, it claims

```
ERROR: could not open file /directory2/file3.jl
```

How come it does not find my files? It runs just fine, without the debugger. Do I need to change some PATH variable (REPL?) or something to tell it where to look for files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you're `include`ing those files? If so, that's a [bug](https://github.com/JunoLab/Juno.jl/issues/569) in Juno's debugger.

Until this is fixed, you can either

- use absolute paths in your include statements, e.g. `include("/foo/bar/baz.jl")` instead of `include("baz.jl")`
- or directly enter the function call (with e.g. `Juno.@enter start()` or the "Run Block" command).

Comment: In my main file, I include the other files, so that should be no issue. Could you precise the method you would use without using Juno command line? I'll see if that works (since I'm pretty sure I didn't do your method at first, which is why it didn't work).

Comment: The workaround on your side would be to use absolute paths in your `include` statements, e.g. `include("/foo/bar/baz.jl")` instead of `include("baz.jl")`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't test this solution, but I'll assume this is correct. I'll edit your answer to mention the absolute path includes, as well as mention my own answer regarding the Juno command line. All in all, I can accept your answer after you accept my edits.

Comment: Oh, I cannot edit your answer, since "suggested edit queue is full". Please edit in the two additional remarks yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think my error came from the fact that I just opened the debugger panel, without entering the correct command in the Juno command line :

```
Juno.@enter start()
```

where start() is the function that starts my program. Now everything compiles and runs at least.

Comment: Just running a file in the debugger is a valid way to use the debugger and should work (see my answer for why it doesn't in your case).